# How to pass jwt token from one route to another

Tags: node.js, jwt

I have two routes in my node js app: `users` & `records`

In the `users` route I am getting the token on `/login` path:

```
users.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    var token = '';
    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM ${process.env.USER_TBL} WHERE EMAIL = ?`, [email], function(err, results, fields) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(200).json({'message' : err, 'token' : token})
        }
        if (results.length > 0) {
            bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].PASSWORD).then(function(match) {
                if (match == true) {
                    token = jwt.sign(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results[0])), process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
                        expiresIn: 5000
                    })
                    res.status(200).json({'message' : 'User verified', 'token' : token})
                } else {
                    res.status(200).json({'message' : 'Email or Password does not match', 'token' : token})
                }
            })
        } else {
            res.status(200).json({'message' : 'Email does not exists', 'token' : token})
        }
    })
    connection.end(err => {
        if(err) console.log(err);
    })
})
```

In my second route `records` I am making a request to path `/addNewRecord`,

```
records.post('/addNewRecord', function(req, res) {
      //need the token to authenticate the request
});
```

here I need the token generated from `/login` route to send in the hrader and authenticate my request.

but I am understand how can I pass `token` value from `users` route to `records` route.

Answer (score 2):

When you login you transmit your token to the user, capture that token and put it into local storage on the client. Then it available for the next call to the server.

```
localstorage.setItem('token', token)
```

When making your next server request you would use the stored token in your header.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "URL",
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'authorization': localstorage.getItem('token'), //YOUR TOKEN GOES HERE
    'anotherHeader': 'headerValue2'
  }
});
```

Then you can capture the token from the next request to verify it is valid

```js
records.post('/addNewRecord', function(req, res) {
      let token = req.headers['authorization']
});
```

Comment: There's a typo in the controller method, `... req.headers['authrization']` should be `... req.headers['authorization']`

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a token between server side code in that manner. It has to be sent from the client. Whenever `/login` is called from the client side and it receives a response, you can then store the token from that response on the client side. When calling `/addNewRecord` simply add the token in the header of the request on the client side and it can be accessed by inspecting `req.get(headerName)` or `req.headers` on the server side.